# scipy.special import issue

Tags: python, scipy

I have an issue with importing the `scipy.special` package. It isn't harmful, just annoying/interesting.

When I import scipy using `import scipy as sp` and then try to access `sp.special` I get:

```
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> sp.special
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'special'
>>>
```

but if I then do `import scipy.special` I can access the special module through `scipy.special` and `sp.special`:

```
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> import scipy.special
>>> scipy.special
<module 'scipy.special' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.pyc'>
>>> sp.special
<module 'scipy.special' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

So I now have the `special` module accessible through both `sp` and `scipy` namespaces. The interesting bit is that I can access the rest of scipy through the `scipy` namespace.

First question: Why does the `special` module not import first time round?

Second question: How can I get access to the `special` module through the `sp` namespace only, without defining the `scipy` namespace?

Edit: using Python 2.7.2 and scipy 0.10.1

Answer (score 52, accepted):

By default, "import scipy" does not import any subpackage. There are too many subpackages with large Fortran extension modules that are slow to load. I do not recommend doing `import scipy` or the abbreviated `import scipy as sp`. It's just not very useful. Use `from scipy import special`, `from scipy import linalg`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will bear that in mind in future. Is there anywhere in the docs that explicitly states this? I can't see such a comment in the [API](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.1/reference/api.html) document

Comment: I know it's an old comment, but it is still a FAQ, so here's one resource: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html#guidelines-for-importing-functions-from-scipy