# Apply math.erf to an array

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, vectorization

I am using math.erf to find the error function of each element in an array.

```
# Import the erf function from the math library
from math import erf
# Import the numpy library to represent the input data
import numpy as np

# Create a dummy np.array
dummy_array = np.arange(20)

# Apply the erf function to the array to calculate the error function of each element
erf_array = erf(dummy_array)
```

I am getting an error as I cannot apply this whole function to an array. Is there a way to apply the error function to the whole array (vectorised approach) without looping through each element and applying it? (The loop will take a lot of time as the tables will be large)

Comment: The whole point of numpy that you don't have to use built-in math. What about [`scipy.special.erf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.erf.html)?

Comment: It's not showing up on my python. Do you have it?

Comment: I'm seeing erf_zeros, erfcinv, erfinv

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "not showing up"?

Comment: I return an unresolved reference in trying to call it and pycharm usually suggests functions that are available in the library

Comment: well, it's there. It's unusual that I don't get suggestions for it though like I usually would

Comment: Do you want to provide a basic answer for the validation?

Comment: @78282219 are you sure you have `scipy` installed on your system? Try `pip install scipy`

Comment: I found it but it doesn't show up on suggested, must be some reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from scipy import special
import numpy as np

dummy_array = np.arange(20)
erf_array = special.erf(dummy_array)
```

It is essential that you import the `special` subpackage as `from scipy import special`. Importing just `scipy` as `import scipy` and then calling `scipy.special.erf()` won't work, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819733/scipy-special-import-issue) and [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/#guidelines-for-importing-functions-from-scipy).

Comment: I mean... you could just do `import scipy.special` then use `scipy.special.erf`.

Comment: Is this actually faster than looping with math.erf()?

Comment: @Anonymous: yes, even for the given example with 20 elements I get 4 µs for `%timeit special.erf(dummy_array)` and 12 µs for `%timeit np.array([math.erf(element) for element in dummy_array])` (and 7 µs without array creation). For larger arrays the difference becomes bigger.

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension to apply the function to each element at once
`erf_array = [erf(element) for element in dummy_array)]`

Comment: This will end up with a usual Python list, not a numpy array, which I presume OP wants implicitly. In this case the list should be fed to numpy’s `array` function, so that might be not as efficient due to reallocation.